# It's "not an answer", but generated possible useful conversation

Tags: support

I've been watching a question that somewhat pertains to an issue I'd like to address at work. Sadly, the last activity on the question was nearly three weeks ago. The only answer to this question is "*not an answer*" and is acknowledged as "*comment-ish*" by the poster, with a promise to delete it should it become obsolete. The *answer* generated a small conversation with the OP author. This did not lead to an overall solution, but it may have added some clarity and eliminated possible assumptions about the problem.

[image: Not-an-answer-generated conversation]

No part of this conversation has made its way into the OP via editing, so I've hesitated to flag yet. Any editing seems like it would be a significant amount of change to the OP however, so I've not done that either. Or am I altogether wrong about the usefulness of the information shown here? (I'm not really qualified to say that it's not helpful considering I don't know the answer to begin with.)

What is the appropriate action to take here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614787/speed-up-6-000-row-query-with-zend-framework-2/31615569#31615569

Comment: Via Tavern: "*NAA, add any pertinent info to the question*" - *BradleyDotNET*

Comment: My Suggested Edit to the question was hands down rejected. X_x

Comment: It looks like the main thing that made the answer "difficult to put in a comment" was that in a comment, all of the code would be inline, making it hard to read.  Perhaps line breaks in code in comments should be supported.  The comment character limit would not need to be changed.

Comment: @OhBeWise: who rejected it? If info helps answer the question while not being an answer; its place is in the question itself and nowhere else. Nobody should be forced to read all the comments before answering a question.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9141993) the edit review. User Yakk, in the comments section of ryanyuyu's answer here, suggested my lack of adding a link to the discussion thread could have contributed to the reject votes - as changing the OP's intent - which seems probable. But ryanyuyu has since made the same edit to address the situation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the question is on-topic, I'd recommend editing the information from the non-answer comment thread into the question and then pinging the answerer to delete their post (since they said they would).  Or if they don't delete it, flag it as NAA.  Since the post itself claims it's not an answer, the mods probably won't reject it (even though it look kinda like an answer at first glance).

Obviously, if the question is off-topic just flag/close it instead.

Comment: Did you mean to write "delete the question" where you did?

Comment: @hobbs thanks. Fixed that.

Comment: Note that when you edit the information into the question, you should note that it came from a discussion below (and provide a link to said discussion), so it doesn't look like you are changing the OP's intent.

Comment: @Yakk I made a note in the Edit comment, but failed to do so in the edit itself. Perhaps that is why it was [rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9141993)?

Comment: @ohbewise There was also a lack of link to said discussion.  In general, when making substantial edits like that, you need to make the burden of proof really easy on the reviewers -- they will (quite rightly) see a wall of added code and say "really?"

Comment: @OhBeWise that is really too bad that your suggestion was rejected.  I think you did a good job with your suggested edit.  I'll put in that edit a bit later when I have more time.

Answer (score 5):

Since editing the question didn't work, and I'm not sure it should have, I would suggest adding a comment to the question explaining what information needs to be added to his question.

From the sounds of things in its current state the question should be closed for being unclear, too broad and/or asking for debugging help without an minimal, complete and verifiable example (MCVE). If so flag the question to be closed for the appropriate reason. If you haven't already, flag the answer for being Not an Answer (NAA).

If that doesn't result in the in original poster updating his question with the necessary information, and it probably won't, then the next step I would recommend is to post your own question. Since you have a similar problem you should be able to post your own question that isn't missing any necessary information. You don't have to worry about your new question being closed as a duplicate if the other person's question is unanswered.

Answer (score -9):

Sometimes, as here, the NAA rule is silly.

Change the first two sentences of the answer to something like:

> "To solve the problem, do this..."

or perhaps

> "The answer to your problem is to..."

and all's well.  It's fairly common that the "answer" is actually a process which you have to do, to, lead to the solution - this is an exact example of that.  It's quite common.

Comment: I don't think the NAA rule is silly, but people make mistakes in applying it, and others make mistakes in formulating their answers that lead to mistakes in applying the rule.  I agree with everything else you say.  I think that in this case, what was provided really was an answer, even though the poster didn't see it as such.  Properly presented, it should look sometime like this: "To speed up your code, you need to benchmark it to figure out where the bottleneck is.  Here's an illustration, which might show you where your problem is. ..."  (*Your* answer shouldn't have been downvoted, IMO.)

Comment: I worry about qualifying "*process[es] which [...] lead to the solution*" as standalone answers. To me, they are the polar opposite of code only answers - answers that give purely a solution with no explanation of the *why*. Whereas the former outlines the *why* or *what* went wrong, but doesn't so much say how to fix it. -One without the other is an incomplete answer imho. The "properly presented" example @Mars gives of the OP in question I think is excellent and a valid answer. But the OP answer as presented, to me, is effectively "do X and give Y updated info."

Comment: Hi OhBeWise .. for many QA, the answer, really, has nothing to do with code, and code cannot be given.  "One without the other is an incomplete answer imho...." The solution to the problem at has is often "you must profile in this manner by pressing these buttons" or "if you insert a log statement here here and here you will determine which of these problems x y z is at hand".

Comment: @JoeBlow Valid point. I hadn't considered (for lack of a better term) user-action-needed solutions.

Comment: these are the issue that make one lose sleep.  it's fine for me to be a smartass and sit back and criticize the obvious silly features of SO, but ... is SO about one billion times better than the typical forum?  yes.  So, who knows.

Comment: There are paradigmatic SO answers (sometimes posted as comments!), and there are paradigmatic SO non-answers, and ... coding being the messy world that it is, there are gray areas.  The answer we're discussing falls in the gray area, but the poster really did, understandably, view it as a comment.  (It's now been deleted, after it was added to the question.)  I don't know what the policy should be, except that helpfulness should be encouraged.  And maybe additional code formatting should be allowed in comments.

Comment: Full disclosure: I occasionally post extensive debugging tips as answers, rather than downvoting or flagging  poor questions about a tool with very few posts, most of them by newbie programmers.  That's the nature of the tool--it's mostly newbies that need help.  Those of us who have a little bit of experience with it tend to be very tolerant, and help directly rather than flagging.  This wouldn't work with a heavily-trafficked tag like [java].  SO needs rules that will keep the problematic cases from getting out of hand, but maybe OK to bend the norms in subcommunities where doing so works.